# Google Analytics track 2 domains (one with subfolder)

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains

I want to get the GA data with this setup:

- Main domain: mydomain.com
- Second domain: subdomain.myotherdomain.com/myfolder

So basically I want the visits to the main domain and the visits to the second domain to count as one page. The reason for that second domain is to redirect user to a secure area. That secure area is located in a subfolder, not in the root of the second domain.

I thought that as long as I put the same tracking ID everywhere it would be fine, but donig some research I found this from Google: [Set up cross-domain tracking for multiple domains](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&utm_id=ad)

Do I need this in my case? If so, how do I tell GA about just tracking the specific folder in the second domain? I will have other folders in the future that will need to be tracked separately from this account, so that's why I only want that folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need this (or else visits from mydomain.com to myotherdomain.com will be counted as two different visitors with mydomain.com as refering site).

You can use _setCookiepath (in the code for myotherdomain.com )  to limit the Google Analytics cookie to your subdirectory:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/myfolder']);
```

(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCookiePath)